# Check if object exist in collection with only name

Tags: c#, collections

Im using observer collection and check as follwos if an object is exist on it,
but now I need to check if the object exist without the object instance just the name
how can i do that?

if( UserList.Contains(user))

this is the userlist definition

```
        public ObservableCollection<User> UserList
        {
            get { return _UsersList; }
        }
```

There is situation when I have just user **name** and not the user object ...

Comment: Did you try with LINQ? UserList.Any(x => name.Equals(x.Name)

Comment: @Adriano actually no need to use `Equals` in this case, it's not Java...

Comment: @KonradMorawski not (strictly) necessary but it's a good practice to always use Equals to compare strings (actually specifying StringComparer too, here omitted just for brevity). "==" operator is a very special case (current culture, case sensitive) and it's a shortcut I'd avoid everytime I want to be sure who reads code is aware he is comparing strings (aware = he understand full implications and what a string comparison is). How often? 100% of times...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **LINQ** to check if any user exist with that name:

```
UserList.Any(u => u.Name == "nameToCheck");
```

Comment: `Any` is extension method over `IEnumerable` and not belong to ObservableCollection. You need to add namespace `System.Linq` to use that.

Comment: Thanks Rohit voted up! just one last question ,there is option to remove item from the user list with something similar like _modelViewInstance.UserList.Remove(u => u.Name == txtBox.Text);   ?

Comment: `var user = UserList.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name == "nameToCheck");` will get you item if exist otherwise it will return null.

Comment: Check for null and then remove it if not null. `if(user != null) { UserList.Remove(user); }`.

Comment: I can do this just if I have the user instance but in this case I dont have it ,just the user name..

Comment: In my posted answer, you don't need instance. With FirstOrDefault you will get already present object in list with that user name and remove that from list.

Comment: Sorry I didnt get since the any return boolean,can you provide simple example please?

Comment: Sorry I found it ,Thanks Expert!